# Map container not found leaflet nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

Всем привет!
Этот вопрос задаю с целью добавить собственное решение, тк мало информации нашел сам по этой проблеме. Я еще джун, следовательно, вполне могу ошибиться в информационной точности, поэтому буду рад конструктивным замечаниям или более оптимальным решениям!)

использую плагин leaflet с nuxt js столкнулся с 2 последовательными проблемами:

1. import L from "leaflet" - window is not defined. Проблема возникла при импорте плагина в компонент

   import L from "leaflet";
   import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
2. Map container not found - возникает сразу после решения пункта 1.

Answer (score 0):

1. window is not defined - возникает в следствии того, что `<div id="map" ref="map"></div>` еще не определен на момент загрузки плагина.

Мне помогло такое решение:

```
<script>
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

let L = {};

if (process.client) {
   L = require('leaflet')
   require('~/plugins/leaflet-arrowheads');
}
...
mounted() {
if (!this.$refs.map) {
  this.map = L.map('map', { attributionControl: false }).setView({ lon: 30.315871, lat: 59.939096 }, 13);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 19 }).addTo(this.map);
  L.control.attribution({ prefix: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }).addTo(this.map);
  L.control.scale({ imperial: false, metric: true }).addTo(this.map);
}
```

Но, сразу после этого, прилетает ошибка:
2. `Map container not found`

Мне показалось вот это хорошим решением, но, к сожалению, мне оно не помогло. Может поможет Вам, поэтому оставлю ссылку: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047564/vuejs-leaflet-map-container-not-found

Свою проблему я смог решить через обычный `setTimeout`:

```
...
mounted() {
if (!this.$refs.map) {
setTimeout(() => {
    this.map = L.map('map', { attributionControl: false }).setView({ lon: 30.315871, lat: 59.939096 }, 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 19 }).addTo(this.map);
    L.control.attribution({ prefix: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }).addTo(this.map);
    L.control.scale({ imperial: false, metric: true }).addTo(this.map);
  }, 1000)
}
```